# Passing local storage value from client side to server side in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am new to node js.

I need to pass local storage value from client side to server side.

If anyone know how to do this please let me know.

Comment: The only way to do this is over the network. There's a couple ways, most popular are sending an HTTP request or transferring data over a WebSocket connection. Your question is lacking some information about the channel the client and the server communicate over. You probably want to [read on HTTP transactions with Node backend](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction/), too. Please improve your question to help us help you.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Sure i will improve my question